# What is the best way to handle excluding items from a list via a user search?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a list of items and a user can search through the list. The list will at most be about 100 items all the data exists at run time so when searching no ajax request need to be made to get new list items, I just have to filter all existing items for the search term.

Is it better for performance if I just add class that hides the list items that don't match the search, or would it be better in the render method to only render the items that match the search. Assuming there is no search initially and all items are rendered on mount, wouldn't removing items because they don't match the users search term after mount be more costly than just adding a class to hide these items?

There are click handlers on the items in case it matters.

As the list will only be at most 100 items I would prefer to just hide them via a class but am not sure if this is really the react way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with re-rendering the result list to only display the matching items in the list.

Hiding the non matching results has several drawbacks:

- a bloated html with up to 100% items in `display: none` in case the search has no results...
- it is probably more costly because you're re-rendering the html in order to apply the css class to hide the items

React is clever when it comes to updating the dom, so it's not really "react way" to tell him which items to hide. Just send the new list of items with the propre keys for each one.